# Pricing for Firebase Blaze plan associated with Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-test-lab

Today I started using GCP combined with the Firebase Blaze plan. I Received the 300$ free-trial credit and few more vouchers. Firebase also automatically upgraded to Blaze. I'm wondering if these vouchers cover all the Firebase services...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase projects automatically become pay-as-you-go project projects if you attach a Cloud billing account to them. It's an interesting quirk of the ongoing integrations between Cloud and Firebase, and we'll hopefully get some checks and alerts in place at some point in the future to make this less surprising.

As for the charges, Firebase projects are billed through Cloud like any other Cloud project. In other words, your free credits will be applied.

In addition, Firebase now has [a free usage tier on Blaze](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/adding-free-usage-to-blaze-pricing-plan.html), so you still won't be charged for any Firebase usage if you stay within the free allotment.

Comment: The issue of firebase projects automatically becoming  becoming pay-as-you-go still exists?